# web scraping- response from webpage shows page not found

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

When I get a request in python a link, I get a webpage where the page isn't found- when I copy the link in my browser, it is the same link but gets the link gets modified based on my browser view. How would I retrieve the page contents in this case?

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

link = 'https://www.wikiart.org/en/paintings-by-genre/abstract?select=featured'
page = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
```

`soup` contains a webpage not found. The link isn't wrong though. When I use the browser and go to `link`, the link becomes this: `https://www.wikiart.org/en/paintings-by-genre/animal-painting?select=featured#!#filterName:featured,viewType:masonry` and I'm able to view contents. However, in Python, I guess the link isn't being rerouted like my browser does it, so I get the wrong page.

I do not have lots of experience as a web dev, but what is the cause of this? Is it because the website is a web app instead of plain html/css?

Comment: try `page = requests.get(link, allow_redirects=True)`

Comment: yes, that fixes this issue. thank you :)